# Game Center Integration for iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

Im a beginner for developing IOS applications mainly games. I have the game completed and have submitted it to the app store. In the mere future I want to submit an update which will include game center, primarily leader boards for scores (all time, monthly, weekly, and today). I'm having trouble understanding how to integrate the completed game with game-center. Another part that is unclear to me is what do I write in the code and how does gamekit framework know which number (score) to submit to game center. If anyone could provide detailed information I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you have a sample project

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html

To send the score you have this function, score is the score, category is the name of the leaderboard you configure on itunes connect.

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category {

GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
myScoreValue.value = score;

[myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
    }

}];
}
```

You have to use this function to send the score when your player is killed, you don't have to track if it has been the highest, but you can track if it's greater than 0;

This tutorial uses the sample project functions in his own project, take a look, it includes sending points and achivements

http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-game-center-basics-leaderboards-and-achievements/

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately stackoverload won't let me vote up.

Comment: I edited the answer, not is a bit simpler. You can't upvote, but I supose you can accept the answer

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Now its 100x times clear to me than before.

Answer (score 2):

Game Center is available since iOS SDK 4.1

1) Open the Xcode Help.

2) On the top you should see a navigation bar, which should say "Documentation" section and move your mouse to where it says "iOS 5.1 Library"(in my case).

3) Now, move your mouse over "Networking & Internet" and click on it.

4) You now should have a list of available APIs.

After that just look around for the APIs you want, like **Leaderboards**, and **achievements**. 
According to your requirements you should look for things like **GKLeaderboards**, and anything else you are interested in.  Those documentations should link to other documentations you would need. You can find the [GKLeaderboards documentation on web](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

**Edit:** The game which you developed would be showing some score to the player after each instance of the Game. Post that score to the function `- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category`  eg. `[self.gameCenterManager reportScore:yourscore forCategory: @"yourgamecategory"];`

For the GameCenterManager.h and GameCenterManager.m from this link

Comment: Okay that helps. My biggest misunderstanding is how does the actual game know which score to send to gamecenter? Such as what do you write in the code to send the score. For instance, when my character in the game gets killed, theres a screen that shows the final score. In this source file what do I put to send that score?

Comment: what is the forCategory section for. Is it for the different leaderboards such as today, week, month, year

Comment: Checkout the Leaderboard Categories under [LeaderBoard Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html)

Comment: it doesnt let me. I tried to vote up but it say i need 15 "rep". Idk what that is

Answer (score 0):

update score to game center use this routine.

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score   :(NSString*) YOUR_LeaderBoard_ID
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:YOUR_LeaderBoard_ID];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            IsConnectFail = true;
        }else{
            IsConnectFail = false;   
        } 
    }]; 
}
```